# Upgrading MySQL from 5.1 to 5.5 - InnoDB plugin question

Tags: mysql, innodb, upgrade

I am planning an upgrade of some MySQL servers (5.1 to 5.5). I am aware that the InnoDB plugin is now built in to MySQL.

Currently we use the InnoDB plugin...

When upgrading to 5.5, is it just a case of removing the relevant lines in my.ini that load the plugin before restarting the server, or is there something I need to do (or should be doing) to the databases and tables in addition to this to take account of the change?

Will the tables just "pick up" the change to the storage engine, or do they need to be converted in some way.

I don't intend on doing a dump and reload of the tables as there are many large databases and this would be a bit of a pain!

Hope this all makes sense!

thanks!

Comment: blongs on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

- Remove or comment out the plugin options in my.cnf or my.ini file.
- Upgrade MySQL.
- Run [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html) script which does the following.

  mysqlcheck --all-databases --check-upgrade --auto-repair
  mysql < fix_priv_tables
  mysqlcheck --all-databases --check-upgrade --fix-db-names --fix-table-names

MySQL Manual recommends doing the dump and reload instead of running mysql_upgrade script as it is a safer way to upgrade.

Review [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading.html) for all details on upgrade steps and gotchas along the way.

Comment: For some reason I could not make the code block display formatted as code after I added list items.